# Rails 5: styling a user chat using ActionCable and Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, actioncable

I'm creating a chatroom with Rails 5 and ActionCable. I followed the [video on GoRails](https://gorails.com/episodes/group-chat-with-actioncable-part-1?autoplay=1) to set it up.

I'd now like to style the messages depending on whether `current_user` sent the message or not.

This is my **views/messages/_message.html.erb** partial:

```
<div class="<%= message.user == current_user ? 'bubble' : 'bubble bubble-alt' %>">
  <%= message.body %>
</div>
```

The styling works if I just refresh the page. The problem is that when the Sidekiq job renders this partial (which triggers a `MessagesController.render(message)`), it doesn't know who the `current_user` is because it doesn't have the proper context and so the chat fails to work.

My question is, how can I allow users to send messages between each other and style them depending on whether they were the senders or not using ActionCable + Sidekiq?

Here are the other relevant files:

**message_relay_job.rb**

```
class MessageRelayJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :high

  def perform(message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast("chatrooms:#{message.chatroom.id}",
      {
        message: MessagesController.render(message),
        chatroom_id: message.chatroom.id
      }
    )
  end
end
```

**chatrooms_channel.rb**

```
class ChatroomsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    current_user.chatrooms.each do |chatroom|
      stream_from "chatrooms:#{chatroom.id}"
    end
  end

  def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end

  def send_message(data)
    @chatroom = Chatroom.find(data['chatroom_id'])
    message = @chatroom.messages.create(body: data['body'], user: current_user)
    MessageRelayJob.perform_later(message)
  end
end
```

**chatrooms.coffee**

```
if $("meta[name='current-user']").length > 0
  App.chatrooms = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ChatroomsChannel",
    connected: ->
      # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

    disconnected: ->
      # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

    received: (data) ->
      # Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
      active_chatroom = $("[data-behavior='messages'][data-chatroom-id='#{data.chatroom_id}']")
      if active_chatroom.length > 0
        active_chatroom.append(data.message)
      else
        $("[data-behavior='chatroom-link'][data-chatroom-id='#{data.chatroom_id}']").css("font-weight", "bold")

    send_message: (chatroom_id, body) ->
      @perform "send_message", {chatroom_id: chatroom_id, body: body}
```

**cable.js**

```
(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});
  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer("/cable");
}).call(this);
```

**chatrooms.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $('#new_message').on 'keypress', (e) ->
    if e && e.keyCode == 13
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).submit()
  $('#new_message').on 'submit', (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    chatroom_id = $("[data-behavior='messages']").data("chatroom-id")
    body        = $('#message_body')
    App.chatrooms.send_message(chatroom_id, body.val())
    # Clear out the message box
    body.val("")
```

**channels/application_cable/connection.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', "User #{current_user.email} - id: #{current_user.id}"
    end

    private

    def find_verified_user
      verified_user = User.find_by_id(cookies.signed['user.id'])
      if verified_user && cookies.signed['user.expires_at'] > Time.zone.now
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**channels/application_cable/channel.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
  end
end
```

**chatroom_users_controller.rb**

```
class ChatroomUsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_chatroom

  def create
    @chatroom_user = @chatroom.chatroom_users.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
    redirect_to @chatroom
  end

  private

  def set_chatroom
    @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:chatroom_id])
  end
end
```

**chatrooms_controller.rb**

```
class ChatroomsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_chatroom, only: %i[show edit update destroy]

  def show
    @messages = @chatroom.messages.includes(:user).order(created_at: :asc)
  end

  def create
    @chatroom = Chatroom.new(chatroom_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @chatroom.save
        format.html { redirect_to @chatroom, notice: 'Chatroom was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @chatroom }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @chatroom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def messages
    @chatrooms = Chatroom.all
  end

  private

  def set_chatroom
    @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    flash[:warning] = 'Unable to find the specified conversation.'
    redirect_to messages_path
  end

  def chatroom_params
    params.require(:chatroom).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

**messages_controller.rb**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_chatroom

  def create
    message = @chatroom.messages.new(message_params)
    message.user = current_user
    message.save
    MessageRelayJob.perform_later(message)
  end

  private

  def set_chatroom
    @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:chatroom_id])
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

**views/messages/create.js.erb**

```
$('#new_message')[0].reset()
```

**models/chatroom_user.rb**

```
class ChatroomUser < ApplicationRecord
  # Associations
  belongs_to :chatroom
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**models/chatroom.rb**

```
class Chatroom < ApplicationRecord
  # Associations
  has_many :chatroom_users
  has_many :users, through: :chatroom_users
  has_many :messages
end
```

**models/message.rb**

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  # Associations
  belongs_to :chatroom
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :chatroom_users
  has_many :chatrooms, through: :chatroom_users
  has_many :messages
end
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same problem as you, I am completely lost in Actioncable. Actioncable is very difficult to understand. Very few people have an in depth knowledge and I find very difficult to tweak tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood, you can pass params into your render method in your job:

```
ApplicationController.render(
    partial: 'your partial',
    locals: { current_user: current_user and your other locals }
)
```

Also, when you perform your job you should pass as param your current_user

```
MessageRelayJob.perform_later(message, current_user.id)
```

And in your job, you can find current_user.

Comment: Hmm I think what needs to happen is more like this: when `MessagesController.render(message)` gets executed I think I somehow need to render a javascript partial that dynamically sets the class depending on whether the sender is the current user or not. The message will appear differently for both users so I think using js here is a must. However, I'm having problems getting the `render` method to use the `.js.erb` file instead of the `.html.erb` file.

Comment: I finally got it!

Comment: @danig2k if you got it, plz post up your answer. maybe, it helps other.

Comment: @DaniG2k, how did you fix it at the end please? I am facing exactlythe same issue.